# Convert pandas groupby dataframe into heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pandas-groupby, heatmap

I'm trying to find a nice way to visualize the data from publicly available cBioPortal mutation data. I want to plot the co-occurrence of Protein Change (so basically, for each sample ID, does that specific sample have any other mutation also). See the image below:

[image: cBio Portal Database DataFrame]

I want to get this plotted as a heatmap (example below):

[image: mutation heatmap]

I've managed to get the data into the form of the first image above, but I am completely stuck as to how to go from there to the example heatmap.

I've looked into:

`df.groupby(['Sample ID', 'Protein Change', 'Cancer Type Detailed']).count().unstack('Protein Change'))`

which seems to go in the right direction, but not completely there.

Basically what I want is a heatmap with *Protein Change* on both axis, and a count of how many times those co-exist within a single sample.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What would happen with the different cancer types? I guess you want an heatmap with all of them right?

Comment: yes I was thinking that would be a separate plot, or add that info to hovertext in plotly (which is probably the more difficult option).

Comment: Ideally, I would like to know if these mutations that co-occur the most, also group by the same Cancer Type. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I didn't fully understand the last comment. What do you mean with "also group by the same cancer type"?

Comment: So these mutation that co-occur(the darker colours on the heatmap), do these co-occurances also usually have the same Cancer Type. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, I see, probably it's best to then also build a per-cancer type co-occurence matrix and use it to build the hovertext in the plot with the general heatmap with a breakdown of the co-occurrences in each type, yes

Comment: Oh right, yeah that makes sense! Thanks so much. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample ID': [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
                   'Protein Change': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
                   'Cancer Type Detailed': 'Some type'})
```

```
   Sample ID Protein Change Cancer Type Detailed
0          1              A            Some type
1          1              B            Some type
2          1              C            Some type
3          4              D            Some type
4          4              A            Some type
5          5              C            Some type
6          6              A            Some type
7          6              B            Some type
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build co-occurrence matrix and set diagonal to zero.
ct = pd.crosstab(df['Sample ID'], df['Protein Change'])
co_occurrence = ct.T.dot(ct)
np.fill_diagonal(co_occurrence.to_numpy(), 0)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 5))

# Mask lower triangular for plotting.
mask = np.tril(np.ones_like(co_occurrence))

cmap = sns.light_palette("seagreen", as_cmap=True)
sns.heatmap(co_occurrence, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, square=True, cbar_kws={"shrink": .65})
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: This is working as expected, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you?

```
from itertools import combinations
# create a dataframe with all combinations for each Sample ID
df_combinations = df.groupby('Sample ID').agg({'Protein Change': lambda s: list(combinations(s, 2))})
# transform the obtained dataset to a two column format
df_combinations = pd.DataFrame(df_combinations['Protein Change'].explode().dropna().tolist(), columns=['Protein Change A', 'Protein Change B'])
# count how many times each combination appears
df_counts = df_combinations.groupby(['Protein Change A', 'Protein Change B']).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()
# pivot the df to obtain the desired matrix
df_counts.pivot(index='Protein Change A', columns='Protein Change B', values='count').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hi. This did give me a heatmap, I would just have to go and check that the plot is actually giving me what I expected. Thanks!